# PHP + Modal + FORM + MYSQL

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem trying to work on some code

I have PHP form in MODAL.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
// krerianje kataloga
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$naslov = $_POST['naslov'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

if ($naslov != '' && $status != ''){
    $sql2= "INSERT INTO katalog(naslov,status) VALUES ('$naslov','$status')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$baza);
    $poruka = '<center><hr style="color:green;width:98%"><h3 style="font-size:17px">Vaš katalog je kreiran.<center/></h3><hr style="color:green;width:98%"></center><br>';
}else {
    $poruka = '<center><hr style="color:green;width:98%"><h3 style="font-size:17px">Molimo Vas ispunite sva polja.<center/></h3><hr style="color:green;width:98%"></center><br>';
}
}

?>
```

And in SAME file I have modal:

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="krerianjekataloga" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <h4>Kreiranje Kataloga</h4>
        <form method="POST" name="katalog" action="index.php?stranica=katalog">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="email" class="">Naslov Kataloga</label>
                <input id="naslov" name="naslov" class="required validate" aria-required="true" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <div class="select-wrapper"><span class="caret">▼</span><input class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-cde9ce7d-c5d2-8deb-ad2c-e8a5668916c4" value="Choose your option" style="" type="text"><ul id="select-options-cde9ce7d-c5d2-8deb-ad2c-e8a5668916c4" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 458px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
                                        <li class=""><span>Aktivno</span></li>
                                        <li class=""><span>Neaktivno</span></li></ul>
                                        <select id="status" name="status" class="initialized">
                                            <option value="1">Akivno</option>
                                            <option value="0">Neaktivno</option>
                                        </select></div>
                                        <label>Odaberite status kataloga</label>
                                    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="submit" style="float:right;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn m-b-xs"><i class="material-icons left">input</i>Spremi</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And that not work... why?
I try with ajax and nothing work... 
Thanks!

Comment: `That not work` Okay, do you expect us to guess how it should work or maybe explain?

Comment: its not work because, u didnt set this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what is `type="submit2"` here:

```
<button type="submit2" style="float:right;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn m-b-xs">
<i class="material-icons left">input</i>Spremi</button>
```

You can simply use `<input type="submit">` field

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Because you are checking like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // here must need a field with name submit
```

**Other Suggestions:**

*Stop using `mysql_*` its deprecated and closed in PHP 7, you can use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)* *or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)*

*Or, if you still want to use `<button>` tag than you can check like `if(count($_POST) > 0)`*

*You also need to take of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)* because you code is open for SQL Injection.

Comment: One more from suggestions, its better to use mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM PDO prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

It can not work because of the the `action` that you have set.

Please change this `action="index.php?stranica=katalog"` to `action="$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]"` to `post` to the same page.

Hope this will help.